# how to get correct data from this array?

Tags: php, arrays, string

This answer might seem simple but I am new to PHP and spending way too much time on trying to figure this out.

My array looks like this:

```
        $phone_number[] = array(
            "type" => "home",
            "value" => $customer_phone                    
        );
```

and I have also this:

```
 $customer = array(
                "first_name" => $first_name,
                "phone_numbers" => $phone_numbers,
                "emails" => $emails,
```

I want to retrieve the number for each customer. I have tried this:

```
     for ($j = 0; $j <= count($customer_entries) - 1; $j++) {


      var_dump($customer_entries[$j]->phone_numbers->value);
     }
```

But it gives me an error. It says I am trying to get property of non object, and then it says null.

But when I use:

```
 var_dump($customer_entries[$j]->phone_numbers;
```

it gives me something like this:

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
object(stdClass)#744 (2) {
["type"]=>
string(4) "home"
["value"]=>
string(14) "(555) 555-5555"
 }
}
```

How do I get it to only give me the result of the string named "value"?

Thank you.

Comment: First, you said you have an array, but you're trying to access it as an object. Second, your array in question is named `$customer`, but in your loop, you're trying to use `$customer_entries`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$customer_entries[$j]['phone_numbers']['value']
```

Use it as an array,not an object.

Comment: I've tried it and it says: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array